# find common ratio of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this problem, I need to find the sum.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{30}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

The problem is that the ratio is not conclusive, Any idea how to find the ratio?

Thanks!

Comment: partial fraction it

Comment: The ratio test will never tell you what the sum it; at most it will tell you whether the series converges.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{1}{k(k+1)} = \dfrac{A}{k} + \dfrac{B}{k+1}$ for some $A$, $B$.

Comment: @Arjang If I partial fraction it I get $$\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$$ but $$\frac{1}{k}$$ it the harmonic progressions don't have don't have common ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you speak of the ratio test, maybe you're only concerned with whether the series converges rather than with what the sum is.  That is the most that the ratio test can give you.  If that is what you're concerned with, then you can say
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {k(k+1)} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {k^2}
$$
and that converges, by a simple integral test.

However, we can also say
$$
\frac 1 {k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}
$$
and then we have
\begin{align}
& \overbrace{\left(\frac 1 1 - \frac 1 2\right)}^{k=1} + \overbrace{\left(\frac 1 2 - \frac 1 3\right)}^{k=2} + \overbrace{\left(\frac 1 3 - \frac 1 4\right)}^{k=3} + \cdots + \overbrace{\left( \frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n+1} \right)}^{k=n} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 1 \underbrace{{} - \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 }\ \ \underbrace{{}-\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 3 }\ \ \underbrace{{} - \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 4} -\cdots\cdots\underbrace{{} - \frac 1 n + \frac 1 n} - \frac 1 {n+1} \\[10pt]
= {} & 1 - \frac 1 {n+1} \to 1 \text{ as }n\to\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have other question If I may this series is not geometric series? right? since we cannot find a conclusive ratio

Comment: Definitely it's not a geometric series.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2}+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1})$$ Do you see how to do it now?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)} = (1-\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

So

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1}=1.$$